# jQuery maphilight changing colors dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change colors of maphilight dynamically.

```
reponse = JSON.parse(reponse);
$('area').each(function()  {
    $(this).attr('data-maphilight', '{"stroke":0, "fillColor":"CCFFCC", "fillOpacity":0.3, "alwaysOn":true}');
    // POUR LA CRÉATION DE BD, METS TOUS LES TERRAIN DANS COMMENTAIRES AVEC UN TYPE 1
    // $('#commentaireArea').val( ($('#commentaireArea').val().concat("('"+$(this).attr('id')+"', 1), \n")));   
            })  

  for (var i = 0; reponse.length > i; i++) {
        var test = '#'.concat(reponse[i].nomTerrain);
        $(test).attr('data-maphilight', '{"stroke":0, "fillColor":"FF0000", "fillOpacity":0.3, "alwaysOn":true}');
  }             
$('img[usemap]').maphilight();
```

This works only once. When it comes to a second time, it doesn't ! It changes CSS classes, but not the maphilight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corect way to do it is by using .data() instead of .attr()

```
                reponse = JSON.parse(reponse);

            $('area').each(function()  {
                $(this).data('maphilight', {"stroke":0, "alwaysOn": true, "fillColor":"CCFFCC", "fillOpacity":0.3})                 
                // POUR LA CRÉATION DE BD, METS TOUS LES TERRAIN DANS COMMENTAIRES AVEC UN TYPE 1
                // $('#commentaireArea').val( ($('#commentaireArea').val().concat("('"+$(this).attr('id')+"', 1), \n")));   
            })  

            for (var i = 0; reponse.length > i; i++) {
                var id = '#'.concat(reponse[i].nomTerrain);
                $(id).data('maphilight', {"stroke":0, "alwaysOn": true, "fillColor":"FF0000", "fillOpacity":0.3})
        }
```

works just fine.